# Broadcast UDP to an external network through the Internet

Tags: udp, external, local, broadcast

I have a program that broadcast UDP to my local network, and one host device would read this message and function upon it perfectly.
Now I want to do this job remotely, knowing that where is the reciever host I have a public static IP provided by the ISP, and for example I'm out side this network and I want to broadcast this UDP traffic to it through the Internet, is there any possible routing configuration that would allow this trafic to reach the local network and just explode there ?

And if not. Is there any other way that can make this trafic, instead of broadcasting to be directed to this receiver host directly ? That would require then only some port forwarding in my static ip router.

Answer (score 0):

By RFC, broadcasts cannot be forwarded by routers. Plus, several ISP will filter out such packets anyway. Broadcasts are limited to the local subnet only.

I suggest you look into multicast instead.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're greatly oversimplifying the issues; could you elaborate on how the OP will get a publicly-routed multicast group?

Comment: In this case, i'm afraid that multicast won't work also, since it uses the same ways that a router would block. I'm having a further study about it anyway. Thanks.